# Delegation causes Access Violation when a type alias is declared?

Tags: delphi, implements

I'm using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition, targeting Windows 32-bit.

I'm writing an interface type. Its class internally uses a `TList<T>` (and some other objects). In order to avoid having to write several pass-through one-liner methods, I'm using the `implements` keyword to delegate, like this:

```
program MRE;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  IMyList = interface
    ['{8483DB08-57EA-40D0-BFCE-5E39804CA15B}']
    function Add (const ACard: Cardinal): Integer;
    function GetEnumerator: TList<Cardinal>.TEnumerator;
  end;

  TMyList = class (TInterfacedObject, IMyList)
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    FCards: TList<Cardinal>;
  public
    property Cards: TList<Cardinal>
      read FCards 
      implements IMyList;
  end;

  constructor TMyList.Create;
  begin
    FCards := TList<Cardinal>.Create;
  end;

  destructor TMyList.Destroy;
  begin
    FCards.Free
  end;

begin
  var Test: IMyList := TMyList.Create;
  Test.Add (3);
  for var c in Test do
    WriteLn (c);
  ReadLn
end.
```

This works fine and prints 3, as expected.

However, when I experienced strange crashes in the more complex version of the program, I was able to distill the bug down to the declaration of a type. Just add a single line (anywhere between the type declarations):

```
type
  TCardList = TList<Cardinal>; { **** this isn't even used anywhere! }
```

The code still compiles, but the application now crashes with an Access Violation ('write of address 0x004ee838'). It's not just the call to `Add()`. When you remove that, it still crashes when the `for` loop tries to get the enumerator.

Are there some weird restrictions to delegation that I'm missing here, or could this be a compiler deficiency?

EDIT: As requested in the comments, here is the same code again with the single line that triggers the crash already added:

```
program MRE;
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TCardList = TList<Cardinal>; { **** this isn't even used anywhere! }

  IMyList = interface
    ['{8483DB08-57EA-40D0-BFCE-5E39804CA15B}']
    function Add (const ACard: Cardinal): Integer;
    function GetEnumerator: TList<Cardinal>.TEnumerator;
  end;

  TMyList = class (TInterfacedObject, IMyList)
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    FCards: TList<Cardinal>;
  public
    property Cards: TList<Cardinal>
      read FCards
      implements IMyList;
  end;

  constructor TMyList.Create;
  begin
    FCards := TList<Cardinal>.Create;
  end;

  destructor TMyList.Destroy;
  begin
    FCards.Free
  end;

begin
  var Test: IMyList := TMyList.Create;
  Test.Add (3);
  for var c in Test do
    WriteLn (c);
  ReadLn
end.
```

This produces the crash mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you please update your example to include a [mcve] of the Access Vioation in action?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I don't think I can make the example code above much shorter. If you just wanted me to add a second complete copy of the code with the one line that causes the crash already inserted, I now edited that into the end of the question.

Comment: Using the MRE, I can reproduce the access violation using D10.4.2 (Without recently published patches). The AV effectively does not occur anymore when removing the unused line `TCardList = TList<Cardinal>;`. This looks really like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Then it needs to be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: @ValerianK. Could you create a bug report at https://quality.embarcadero.com/ and publish the number here?